# Regex Search & Replace Dates and .html from internal links in wordpress

Tags: php, regex, wordpress

I have wordpress website, which has dates and .html in urls in internal links, for example

```
https://www.example.com/2022/07/my-first-posts.html
```

i want to remove dates and .html with PHP regex search & replace plugin so urls will look like this

```
https://www.example.com/my-first-posts/
```

how to perform search and replace?

This is screenshot of plugin

[image]

i tried

```
/(\d*)/(\d*)/([A-Za-z0-9-*])(.*?)\.html
```

to perform search and replace but it is not working correctly.

Comment: You didn't quantify the class that is supposed to match the title part at the end. If you also drop the capturing groups that you don't need and tweak quantifiers a little, it could look like this `/\d+/\d+(/[A-Za-z0-9-]*)\.html` which you could substitute with `$1/` to get what you want, provided your plugin supports the syntax. You could also use `\d{4}` and `\d{2}` to more closely represent the year and month bit respectively. See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/kB7Sen/1).